# C function strcpy() randomly change one character

Tags: c, strcpy

I'm learning string functions in C and I can't seem to get my teacher's demo using `strcpy()` to remove white spaces to work on my machine while it works perfectly fine for him. Here's the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s[20]="abc   def   ghi";
    char *ptr = strstr(s, "  ");
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        printf("Before trim: %s\n", s);
        strcpy(ptr, ptr+1);
        printf("After trim : %s\n", s);
        printf("\n");
        ptr = strstr(s, "  ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Expected result:

```
Before trim: abc   def   ghi
After trim : abc  def   ghi

Before trim: abc  def   ghi
After trim : abc def   ghi

Before trim: abc def   ghi
After trim : abc def  ghi

Before trim: abc def  ghi
After trim : abc def ghi
```

Actual result:

```
Before trim: abc   def   ghi
After trim : abc  def   ghi

Before trim: abc  def   ghi
After trim : abc def   ghi

Before trim: abc def   ghi
After trim : abc def  hhi

Before trim: abc def  hhi
After trim : abc def hii
```

I've searched for this error and learned that `strcpy()` is unsafe because it may cause overflow or undefined behavior. Most of the search I've read is about the destination buffer is not large enough. I don't know the keyword of this strange behavior. Can someone please explain to me what am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. According to the manual, source and destination buffer are not allowed to overlap. You violate this rule

Comment: Use a temporary buffer to perform the copy  such as `s1[20]`.

Comment: You can use `memmove` if source and  destination overlap, but you have to compute the length and pass that too. Note that `strcpy` is not guaranteed to fail: it is not guaranteed to succeed, which isn't the same thing.

Comment: I think you should ask your teacher to explain why their code does not work ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
char *strcpy( char *restrict dest, const char *restrict src ); //(since C99)
```

> Copies the null-terminated byte string pointed to by `src`, including the null terminator, to the character array whose first element is pointed to by `dest`.
>
> The [behavior is undefined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) if the `dest` array is not large enough. **The behavior is undefined if the strings overlap**. The behavior is undefined if either `dest` is not a pointer to a character array or `src` is not a pointer to a null-terminated byte string.

https://devdocs.io/c/string/byte/strcpy

This is the kind of thing a teacher should be careful with, though I must say that compiling the code with several versions of MSVC, clang and gcc I was never able to reproduce the described actual result.